# Maven skip module when we package / test

Tags: maven

I have multiple modules in my maven project.

```
  <modules>
    <module>module-1</module>
    <module>module-2</module>
    <module>module-3</module>
  </modules>
```

I would like to skip 1 module , say `module-3` when i do package or test etc. This below profile option does not seem to work.

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <modules>
        <module>module-1</module>
        <module>module-2</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

How to make this work or are there any alternatives?

Comment: Why do you need such a thing, could you please elaborate? In general you can use -pl option: `mvn package -pl module-1, module-2` This will exclude module-3 altogether...

Comment: module-3 is our integration tests. we would need it at later stage.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, let me suggest the following:

1. `module-3` is a module with integration tests. Its ok to compile it with other modules, it will be pretty fast and probably you'll want it anyway, otherwise it will eventually stop to compile. In addition, I don't think you should "play" with module structure like this, because the IDE should open all the modules (probably you open this "main" `pom.xml`)
2. Having said that you will probably want to run the tests only with some kind of flag. In this case you can define a profile for running integration tests instead of running the module.
3. In maven integration tests are usually managed by `failsafe-plugin`. So you can configure this plugin so that it will be actually executed only upon some property. It can be done with maven profiles.